# Как в PyQt при нажатии на кнопку закрыть окно и открыть новое?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня на `PyQt` есть меню игры. При нажатии на кнопку "начать игру", открывается окно, где должна быть игра и закрывается окно главного меню.

Только вот после нажатия на кнопку, когда закрывается главное меню, перед появлением следующего окна *на долю секунды закрывается вообще вся игра*.  
Т.е. бывает момент,когда вообще нет открытых окон.

Как решить эту проблему? Или для моих целей можно реализовать переход к другому окну по другому?

Вот функция,которая работает при нажатии на кнопку:

```
    def go_start(self):
        self.g = Game('s','r','f','d','map1.jpg')   
        self.close()
```

Функция создает экземпляр класса `Game()`, который создает новое окно и показывает его на весь экран. 
Потом сама же функция закрывает окно класса `Main()`, создающего меню и чьим методом является функция `go_start()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не смог получить то, что вы написали, но я бы делал это так:

(установите свое изображение при создании экземпляра `self.g` и попробуйте)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, s, r, f, d, img, parent):
        super(Game, self).__init__()

        print(s, r, f, d, img, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        self.button = QPushButton('End', clicked=self.go_end)

        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def go_end(self):
        self.parent.show()        
        self.hide()    


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.button = QPushButton('Start', clicked=self.go_start)

        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def go_start(self):
        self.g = Game('s','r','f','d','im.png', self)   # 'map1.jpg'
        self.g.showFullScreen()        
        self.hide()    # close()        

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```